# Code generation issue for AsyncAPI definition using java-spring-template

Tags: java, spring-boot, asyncapi

I'm trying to generate the code using this [java-spring-template](https://github.com/asyncapi/java-spring-template) using this [async API](https://pastebin.com/raw/A86Cwg2x) definition. After building it, when I try to start using `./gradlew bootRun` , it gives the following error.

Can someone point out the issue in the definition please?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'signedupOutboundChannel' that could not be found.
```

Comment: I would suggest you report this as a bug in the template itself than a stack overflow question.

Comment: @JonasLagoni thanks. I wanted to see whether this error is happening due to some mistake I did in the async definition.